# TensorFlow Lite and Tracking custom objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0, raspberry-pi4

I am developing a project that includes object recognition and for that I am using a Raspberry PI 4. However, I already managed to do object recognition through TensorFlowLite but, now I needed to do a personalized object recognition does anyone know how can I do this in Python?

I see a video on YouTube from SentDex Channel and i managed to do everything until part 4, but at the minute 14:40 it gives me the following error:

```
E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I try to solve it and i see that the solution is swap "tf" to "tf.compat.v1."

However, ocurred more errors:

```
File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 100, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 91, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 46, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 122, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 84, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Vegan-Mac-and-Cheese-3.jpg; No such file or directory
```

Thank you!